# Creating an inverted index with limited memory in java

Tags: java, file, memory, inverted-index

Im curious on how create an Inverted Index on data that doesn't fit into memory. So right now I'm reading a file directory and indexing the files based on the contents inside the file, I am using a HashMap to store the index. The code below is a snippet from a function I use and I call the function on an entire directory. What do I do if this directory was just massive and the HashMap can't fit all the entries. Yes, This does sound like premature optimization. Im just having fun. I don't want to use Lucene so don't even mention it because I'm tired as to seeing that as the majority answer to "Index" stuff. This HashMap is my only constraint everything else is stored in files to easily reference stuff later on.

Im just curious how I can do this since it stores it in the map like so

```
keyword -> file1,file2,file3,etc..(locations)
keyword2 -> file9,file11,file13,etc..(locations)
```

My thoughts were to create a file which would some how be able to update itself to be like the format above but I feel thats not efficient.

Code Snippet

```
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (String _word : line.split("\\W+")) {
                word = _word.toLowerCase();

                if (!ignore_words.contains(word)) {

                    fileLocations = index.get(word);

                    if (fileLocations == null) {
                        fileLocations = new LinkedList<Long>();
                        index.put(word, fileLocations);
                    }
                    fileLocations.add(file_offset);
                }
            }
        }

        br.close();
```

Update:

So I managed to come up with something, but performance wise I feel this is slow, especially if there was a large amount of data. I basically created a file that would just have to word and its offset on each line the word appeared.Lets name it `index.txt`.

It had the format of like so

```
word1:offset
word2:offset
word1:offset <-encountered again.
word3:offset
etc...
```

I then created multiple files for each word and appended the offset to that file each time it was encountered in the `index.txt` file.

So basically the format of the word files are like so

```
word1.txt -- Format
word1:offset1:offset2:offset3:offset4...and so on
```

each time word1 is encountered in the `index.txt` file it would append it to the `word1.txt` file and add to end.

Then finally, I go through all the word files I created and overwrite the index.txt file with the final output in the index file looking like so

```
word1:offset1:offset2:offset3:offset4:...
word2:offset9:offset11:offset13:offset14:...
etc..
```

Then to finish it up, I delete all the word files.

The nasty code snippet for this is below, its a fair amount.

```
public void createIndex(String word, long file_offset)
{
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(this.file,true));
        writer.write(word + ":" + file_offset + "\n");
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void mergeFiles()
{
    String line;
    String wordLine;
    String[] contents;
    String[] wordContents;
    BufferedReader reader;
    BufferedReader mergeReader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    PrintWriter mergeWriter;

    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.file));

        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            contents = line.split(":");
            writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(
                    new File(contents[0] + ".txt"),true));

            if(this.words.get(contents[0]) == null) 
            {
                this.words.put(contents[0], contents[0]);
                writer.write(contents[0] + ":");
            }

            writer.write(contents[1] + ":");

            writer.close();
        }
        //This could be put in its own method below.
        mergeWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(this.file));

        for(String word : this.words.keySet())
        {
            mergeReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(new File(word + ".txt")));
            while((wordLine = mergeReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                mergeWriter.write(wordLine + "\n");
            }

        }
        mergeWriter.close();

        deleteFiles();

    } 
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void deleteFiles()
{
    File toDelete;
    for(String word : this.words.keySet())
    {
        toDelete = new File(word + ".txt");
        if(toDelete.exists())
        {
            toDelete.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the word occurs multiple times in one file you are also adding that file multiple times to the `fileLocations` list. This is probably not what you want, or is it?

Comment: Well right now I'm doing basic indexing of makeshift directory of Hospital Patients and inside the file has their information so there is no duplicates, but if that was the case I could always check for duplicates before doing anything if I wanted it or not.

Comment: If the hash table is too large you can partition it based on the keyword (e.g., alphabetically, or something similar that makes allowances for the different frequencies of keywords starting with certain letters) and store each  partition in a file.  You will have to keep switching between different hash files, which could impact performance, or you could have a cache of each hash partition in memory.

Comment: How many files/distinct words are you going to have? (Roughly.) Have you considered Bloom filters?

Comment: Well, I'm just doing hospital patients and the word I'm sorting by is the hospital wing they are in so like 8 files and I'm not really familiar with Bloom filters

Comment: Use a database ? No kidding, that is what they are meant for: indexing and manipulating large data that does not fit in memory !

Comment: Yes, that would be optimal @BrunoGrieder, I was just curious how to do without using a db.

Comment: Since I am at it (examples of what people have done to solve this): Distributed Hash Tables. In other words, if it does not fit on you computer memory, spread it on multiple computers. Kademlia is a popular one and not "that hard" to implement. (I guess simple overflow to disk of your table has been mentioned above)

Comment: I tested 3000 files, the total runtime is roughly around 1.65 seconds to index all of them. Is this poor performance?